# Theme_advanced_disable not working in tinymce 4

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

In tinymce 3.x i used `theme_advanced_disable` to disable some buttons but now in tinymce 4.x
i can't disable the buttons, is there instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the migration guide: 
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorial:Migration_guide_from_3.x

To disable button use `toolbar1: "button1 button2 undo redo ...."` (this will let you choose which buttons to show).

Comment: So i can't disable only the buttons i want to remove?
because some times i don't know what buttons i need to show but i know what buttons i need to disable.